# Area Learning permissions in Unity Editor

Tags: google-project-tango

I've got an issue with the Unity Editor telling me that Area Learning permissions isn't being granted.

Is it expected that the Area Learning permission should be granted while running in the editor (5.3.2, Android build target)?

The docs around permissions that I've tried to follow seem a few months out of date and mention API calls that don't appear to be valid in the Gemma SDK.

( https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-user-permissions )

Any pointers on the correct way to do permissions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you run Area Description feature in Unity Editor, you will encounter this warning. Currently, testing with real ADF file requires the APK to be pushed to the device. For general testing, you could try to use the `DeltaPoseController` prefab in the TangoUnitySDK, and set offset to a pose to emulated the relocalization event.